# Seaborn boxplot legends not showing up properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm writing a code using seaborn to display all the numerical columns of a given dataset in the form of boxplots, however I'm confused as to how to properly call the legends for each boxplot as it does not have a built in 'label' parameter.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from itertools import cycle
colors = ['maroon','grey','navy','burlywood','black','aliceblue','beige']
colorCycle = cycle(colors)
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
df = pd.read_csv('dm_office_sales.csv')
numericClassifier = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
newdf = df.select_dtypes(numericClassifier)
columns = newdf.columns.tolist()
n = len(columns)
sns.boxplot(data=df[columns],palette='bright')
plt.suptitle('Boxplots').set_fontname('ariel')
plt.legend(columns,loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is how the legends are being displayed:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Could you share the dm_office_sales.csv file? (or a sample of the data if possible), so that people can try to draw the graph as you showed.

Comment: Why do you want to add a legend when the boxes are already nicely labeled via the x-axis?  Whenever practical, labeling via the x-axis is strongly preferred to a legend.  If you really really want, you can misuse `hue`:  converting the dataframe to long form via `df_long = df.melt(columns=columns)` and calling `sns.boxplot(df_long, x='variable', y='value', hue='variable')`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the label argument for each boxplot, can this code be any helpful ?

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
df = pd.read_csv('dm_office_sales.csv')
numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']).columns
colors = ['maroon','grey','navy','burlywood','black','aliceblue','beige']

for column in numeric_columns:
    sns.boxplot(data=df[column], color=next(colors), label=column)

# Display the legend
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.suptitle('Boxplots').set_fontname('ariel')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```